# Error using python Adafruit_BBIO GPIO and ADC and BeagleBone Black in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to use python and import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO and import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC to read from some pins while I write to others. But I keep getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wajeeh.py", line 4, in 
    ADC.setup()
RuntimeError: Unable to setup ADC system. Possible causes are:
  - A cape with a conflicting pin mapping is loaded
  - A device tree object is loaded that uses the same name for a fragment: helper

here is my code:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO #import GPIO Library
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC

ADC.setup()

outPinA = "P9_12"                    #set outPinA 
outPinB = "P9_14"                   #set outPinB  

GPIO.setup(outPinA, GPIO.OUT)       #make outPin an Output
GPIO.setup(outPinB, GPIO.OUT)

while 1:
    GPIO.output(outPinA, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(outPinB, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(10)
    GPIO.output(outPinA, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(outPinB, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(10)
    GPIO.output(outPinA, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(outPinB, GPIO.HIGH) # Set outPin LOW
    sleep(10)                       
    GPIO.output(outPinA, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(outPinB, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(10)                       
GPIO.cleanup()                     #Release your pins
```

Comment: You running as root or unprivileged user?  Bad system permissions can cause this error if the user is non-privileged.   It's sort of a bug in BBIO, but also misconfiguration... see https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/36

Comment: @BadZen Yup I was running as root. Not sure what else I could do

Comment: What kernel version are you running? (`uname -r`)

Can you pastebin the output of `dmesg` after booting up and trying to run your script?

Answer (score 3):

A similar issue has been solved in a later version of ADC. See: [issue 90](https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/90)

Try uninstalling Adafruit_BBIO, and then installing from the git repository:

```
pip uninstall Adafruit_BBIO
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/
cd adafruit-beaglebone-io-python
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried to uninstall Adafruit_BBIO, pip complained that it couldn't find the file '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_BBIO-1.0.3-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg'. However, continuing on to the next steps allowed me to start using the Adafruit_BBIO.ADC library without problems.