# How to fix "RuntimeError: Unable to setup ADC system. Possible..." when calling ADC.setup()

Tags: python, debian, beagleboneblack

I am trying to read the voltage from one of the analog input ports and my code is throwing an error. The error happens when calling `ADC.setup()` (Adafruit_BBIO). The error is as follows: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "print_voltage", line 3, in 
>       ADC.setup()

RuntimeError: Unable to set up ADC system. Possible causes are:
  - A cape with a conflicting pin mapping is loaded
  - A device tree object is loaded that uses the same name for a fragment: helper

I have tried reinstalling Adafruit_BBIO as mentioned here: [Error using python Adafruit_BBIO GPIO and ADC and BeagleBone Black in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791856/error-using-python-adafruit-bbio-gpio-and-adc-and-beaglebone-black-in-ubuntu-14)

Here is my code for the program.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
from time import sleep
ADC.setup()
while i in range(0,100):
        scale = ADC.read("P9_40")
        print(scale*1.8)
        sleep(.1)
```